# Disable Save and Publish button in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

Do we have any option to disable the save and publish button available in umrbaco programmatically.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the source, here's a down & dirty way to disable it using ApplicationBase to inject some jQuery:

```
public class RemoveToolbarButtons : ApplicationBase
{
    public RemoveToolbarButtons()
    {
        umbracoPage.Load += new umbraco.presentation.masterpages.MasterPageLoadHandler(umbracoPage_Load);
    }

    void umbracoPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var page = (umbracoPage)sender;

        if (page.Page.Request.Path.ToLower().Replace((GlobalSettings.Path + "/").ToLower(), "").Contains("editcontent.aspx"))
        {
            var currentDocId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"]);
            Document d = new Document(currentDocId);
            if (d.ContentType.Alias == "YourDocTypeAlias")
            {
                string s = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.editorIcon').each(function() { if(String($(this).attr('alt')) == 'Save and publish') {$(this).hide(); return false;} });
                });
                </script>";
                page.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "jshidetoolbar", s);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Change YourDocTypeAlias to the doctypealias where you want to disable it.  Note this only hides the button using jQuery, the user may still have access to Publish via the context menu or other methods.

Answer (score 2):

Minor tweak to Tom's approach - adjust the jQuery to not return false (otherwise it only hides the first 'Save and publish' button when you have multiple tabs)

```
string s = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.editorIcon').each(function() { if(String($(this).attr('alt')) == 'Save and publish') {$(this).hide(); } });
                });
                </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The full-source code for Umbraco is available as an open source project, so yes, you can disable the save and publish (and do anything else you want).

[Link](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/)